# Android SDK emulator with full HD resolution

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So, I've just received the fourth e-mail today regarding support for the latest iteration of tablets with a 10-inch screen and a resolution of 1920 x 1200 pixels in one of my apps. The layouts in my app are tailored to look the absolute best for each device type, but it's been impossible for me to launch the SDK emulator with a 1920 x 1200 pixel resolution, and as such I haven't been able to make the layout for this screen size.

I've mentioned the issue to the Android developers team on their weekly Google+ hangouts multiple times (and they didn't really care), I've seen lots of other questions regarding it on Stack Overflow and the web in general and I've also filed two bugs regarding this issue with the Android Tools site. I'm still left with an emulator that won't work at these high resolutions.

There are a few devices on the market with these high resolutions, and I know that the Android OS supports it, so I'm stumbled by the limits of the emulator.

My PC is a power-horse with plenty of power to run it and there's never been issues with lower resolution emulators before. I'd be really happy if anyone can help with this, as it's been driving me nuts.

Comment: complain or question or..? how this community here can help?

Comment: It's really more of a question than a complaint. If anyone has managed to get it working, I'd love to hear from them. I've tried many different combinations and nothing seems to work. It's either just showing a black screen or it crashes.

Comment: "it's been impossible for me to launch the SDK emulator with a 1920 x 1200 pixel resolution" -- this is a singularly unhelpful explanation of your symptoms. "an emulator that won't work" -- this too is beyond useless. Rather than rant, explain *specifically* what is going wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just did, Mark. It's either showing a black screen or it crashes. It really shouldn't be that hard to launch an emulator with a certain resolution. Try it yourself and you'll see.

Comment: The Google TV emulator supports 1080p just fine, albeit on 3.1.

Comment: @CommonsWare It doesn't work on Windows, so that's out of the question.

Comment: Yeah, the emulator definitely seems borked at resolutions higher than WXGA800. Not terribly shocking, but definitely disappointing, as this is not the first time higher-than-expected resolutions have caused problems. Either set up your PC for dual-boot with Linux so you can play with the Google TV emulator, or spring for a 1080p tablet when they become available (Acer Iconia Tab A700 should go on sale tomorrow, at least at Amazon, for $450), or block 1080p tablets in the Play Store until you get an environment that works, I guess.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, that might be the only option out. Just bloody annoying that I have to shift my development environment to another OS because the SDK is bugged.

Comment: Closing this question is utter bullshit. It's VERY clear what's being asked. Four people have upvoted it because they apparently understood what's being asked, so I can't see why it's closed.

Comment: Use AndroVM http://androvm.org/blog/ :)